# Parallax Plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I need to convert a design to HTML CSS and the site uses the latest fad of parallax effect. I did the research and came across a dozen of plugins for the achiving this.

The website has the following features

1. Full Screen Images
2. Tabs
3. SLide Show
4. Map
5. Forms

Which plugin do u suggest and any starting point for me to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal favourite for scrolling parallex is [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/). It has loads of really good examples on their site and is well maintained. For slideshows I use [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), it is really good for basic slideshows and works well within responsive designs. For tabs i usually just use a bit of my own jQuery as plugins can be abit overkill. Hope that helps

Comment: I just used Superscrollorama - it was great for desktop - but suffers hard on mobile (is ok on iphone but terrible on andriod + tablets)

Answer (score 1):

In case you just need to add some background parallax, you can use the parallax background builder described in [this post](http://webdesy.com/parallax-scrolling-builder/)   http://webdesy.com/parallax-scrolling-builder/